# NUnit - prevent 2 specific classes from running in parallel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a test project with many tests and many test classes. Most of them can run in parallel without any problem, but there are 2 specific test classes whose tests access a certain file, and therefore cannot run in parallel.

I guess that if I put `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]` on all other classes and `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.None)]` on these 2 classes, then it should be safe, but AFAIU it also means that these 2 classes won't run in parallel with *any* other class, which is not what I want, as it's not the most efficient solution.

Is there any other, more efficient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points to consider:

- `[Parallelizable]` or `[NonParallelizable]` may be specified on
  multiple levels of the tests, with lower-level specifications
  overriding higher ones to a certain degree.
- It is important to note
  that a parallel or non-parallel specification only applies at that
  level **where it appears and below**. It cannot override the settings
  on higher-level tests.

For your situation, you can create **Parallel class with non-parallel methods**: The methods within this class run sequentially, usually on the same thread that ran the class one-time setup, but may actually be running in parallel with other, unrelated methods from other classes. So your class can be:

```
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
public class MyClass1 
{
    [NonParallelizable]
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
    }

    [NonParallelizable]
    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
    }
}

[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
public class MyClass2 //Another class in same Assembly
{
    //methods within this class will run in parallel with other 
    //class methods within same assembly except method Test1 and Test2 of MyClass1
}
```

Hope this helps. Details [here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in facility in NUnit to do this.

You could check for availability of the file in each class's OneTimeSetUp, blocking until the file is available. This would tie up one thread if the classes were enqueued at the same time but you could allow for that by increasing the level of parallelism for the run.